# How to implement login page using Spring Security so that it works with Spring web flow?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflow

I have a web application using Spring 2.5.6 and Spring Security 2.0.4. I have implemented a working login page, which authenticates the user against a web service. The authentication is done by defining a custom authentincation manager, like this:

```
<beans:bean id="customizedFormLoginFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <custom-filter position="AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER" />
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.do" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="/login.do?error=true" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="customAuthenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationManager"
    class="com.sevenp.mobile.samplemgmt.web.security.CustomAuthenticationManager">
    <beans:property name="authenticateUrlWs" value="${WS_ENDPOINT_ADDRESS}" />
</beans:bean>
```

The authentication manager class:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager, ApplicationContextAware {

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

                //authentication logic

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, authentication.getCredentials(),
                grantedAuthorityArray);
    }
```

The essential part of the login jsp looks like this:

```
<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" var="formUrlSecurityCheck"/>
<form method="post" action="${formUrlSecurityCheck}">
    <div id="errorArea" class="errorBox"> 
       <c:if test="${not empty param.error}">
          ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
      </c:if>
  </div>
    <label for="loginName">
        Username:           
        <input style="width:125px;" tabindex="1" id="login" name="j_username" />
    </label>

    <label for="password">
        Password:           
        <input style="width:125px;" tabindex="2" id="password" name="j_password" type="password" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" tabindex="3" name="login" class="formButton" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Now the problem is that the application should use [Spring Web Flow](http://www.springsource.org/webflow). After the application was configured to use Spring Web Flow, the login does not work anymore - the form action to "/j_spring_security_check" results in a blank page without error message. What is the best way to adapt the existing login process so that it works with Spring Web Flow?

**Edit:** there was no error message, just a blank page was displayed. It works now - the problem was that web.xml was missing entries

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Since I cannot cancel the bounty although the problem is solved, the bounty is awarded to most insightful answer or link, which would help other people in configuring Spring Security and Web Flow to work together.

Answer (score 2):

Here's documentation describing why the 'springSecurityFilterChain' is needed.

The springSecurityFilterChain filter is not created explicitly, but created implicitly by the `<http>` spring security schema element in the application context

```
<http auto-config="false" session-fixation-protection="none">
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/home.htm" />
</http>
```

The beans created require an authentication provider, so we provide one

```
<authentication-provider>
   <user-service id="userDetailsService">
      <user password="password" name="username" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
   </user-service>
</authentication-provider
```

With these changes in place, including configuration of the security filter as described in the edited question, the page will render correctly and the configured security stack will be in place on each page served.

These details and a walk-through a simple spring-security application is given in [A aimple web application with Spring Security - part 13](http://heraclitusonsoftware.wordpress.com/software-development/spring/simple-web-application-with-spring-security-part-13/).

The reference documentation describes setting up the `springSecurityFilterChain` as the first part of configuring web.xml: [Security Namespace Configuration - Getting Started](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-getting-started).
(Linked to 2.0.x version used by the OP. The latest version 3.1 is [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-getting-started).)

Answer (score 1):

From your code it is not clear if you have Spring Security configuration at all. I assume you do not.

- You have to add security name space into your configuration. Something like this

  ```
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ... skipped ...
      xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
      ... skipped ...
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd">
  ```
- You need to configure Spring Security. For example:

  ```
  <security:http once-per-request="false" auto-config="false">
      <security:form-login login-page="path/to/your/login.jsp"/>
  </security:http>
  ```
- This might be enough for it to "just work", but I think you should take a look at implementing your [AuthenticationProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/providers/AuthenticationProvider.html) and not AuthenticationManager. In this case you would need config similar to this:

  ```
  <bean class="my.company.project.MyAuthProvider"
        autowire="byType">
      <security:custom-authentication-provider/>
  </bean>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your app to use Spring Web Flow in accordance with the [Securing Flows](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/ch07.html) chapter of the [Spring Web Flow Reference Guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I've had to change my form name from j_security_check to something else on glassfish, since it seems to interpret that url itself.